# How to prevent auto scroll down on tab2 when user scroll down on tab1 in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-sliver

I created a screen using `SliverAppBar`, `SliverPersistentHeader`, `TabView` and `ListView`.

If I scroll down in tab1, tab2 scrolling down automatically. So If I swith  to tab2, list not starting from first item.  How can I prevent this?

I created simple demo app for demonstrate the issue, you can look at this [gist](https://gist.github.com/mesuutt/5d892bf0b5f3f0bbf36e19bda2d1a49d).

Initial state of the screen:
[image: 1]

If I scroll tab1 shown as below:
[image: 2]

Tab2 scrolling down automatically shown as below when I scroll tab1:
[image: 3]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54689594/flutter-tabsview-and-nestedscrollview-scroll-issue#54689799 looks similar

Answer (score 1):

I have modified your [gist](https://gist.github.com/mesuutt/5d892bf0b5f3f0bbf36e19bda2d1a49d) with PageStorageKey. See below working example:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() async {
    runApp(new TestApp());
}


class TestApp extends StatelessWidget {
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return new MaterialApp(
            theme: new ThemeData(primarySwatch: Colors.yellow),
            home: new TestAppHomePage(),
        );
    }
}

class TestAppHomePage extends StatefulWidget {

    @override
    State createState() => new TestAppHomePageState();
    //FPDetailScreen({Key key, @required this.period}) : super(key: key);
}

class TestAppHomePageState extends State<TestAppHomePage>
        with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {

        return new Scaffold(
            //bottomNavigationBar: bottomNavBar,
            body: DefaultTabController(
                length: 2,
                child: NestedScrollView(
                    headerSliverBuilder: (BuildContext context, bool innerBoxIsScrolled) {
                        return <Widget>[
                            SliverAppBar(
                                expandedHeight: 120.0,
                                floating: false,
                                forceElevated: innerBoxIsScrolled,
                                backgroundColor: Colors.green,
                                pinned: true,
                                flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
                                    collapseMode: CollapseMode.pin,
                                    centerTitle: true,
                                    title: Text(
                                        "Foo Bar Baz",
                                        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                                        textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                                        overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                        softWrap: true,
                                        maxLines: 1,
                                    ),
                                    background: Container(
                                        alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
                                        child: Column(
                                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                                            children: <Widget>[
                                                Row(
                                                    children: <Widget>[
                                                        Text(
                                                            '10.00 TL',
                                                            style: TextStyle(
                                                                    color: Colors.white,
                                                                    fontSize: 20.0,
                                                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                                                        ),

                                                    ],
                                                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                                ),
                                                Container(
                                                    width: 0,
                                                    height: 0,
                                                )
                                            ],
                                        ),
                                    ),
                                    //background: ,
                                ),
                            ),
                            SliverPersistentHeader(
                                pinned: true,
                                delegate: _SliverAppBarDelegate(
                                    TabBar(
                                        tabs: [
                                            Tab(
                                                child: Text(
                                                    "Tab1",
                                                    style: TextStyle(
                                                            color: Colors.black,
                                                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                                                ),
                                            ),
                                            Tab(
                                                child: Text(
                                                    "Tab2",
                                                    style: TextStyle(
                                                            color: Colors.black,
                                                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                                                ),
                                            ),
                                        ],
                                    ),
                                ),
                            ),
                        ];
                    },

                    body:TabBarView(
                            //controller: _tabController,
                            children: [
                                CardList('one'),
                                CardList('two'),
                    ]),
                ),
            ),

        );

    }
}

class _SliverAppBarDelegate extends SliverPersistentHeaderDelegate {
    _SliverAppBarDelegate(this._tabBar);

    final TabBar _tabBar;

    @override
    double get minExtent => _tabBar.preferredSize.height;
    @override
    double get maxExtent => _tabBar.preferredSize.height;

    @override
    Widget build(
            BuildContext context, double shrinkOffset, bool overlapsContent) {
        return new Container(
            color: Colors.white,
            child: _tabBar,
        );
    }

    @override
    bool shouldRebuild(_SliverAppBarDelegate oldDelegate) {
        return false;
    }
}




class CardList extends StatelessWidget {
    final String listKey;

    CardList(this.listKey);

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Container(
            child: ListView.builder(
                    key: PageStorageKey<String>(listKey),
                    scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                    shrinkWrap: true,
                    itemCount: 20,
                    //itemExtent: 1.0,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index){
                        return new ListTile(
                            title: new Text("Item $index"),
                        );
                    }),
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Not worked. Tab2 should not be scrolled when I scroll at tab1 or vice verse.

Comment: It's working as expected for me, have a look at the screen record: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1lyIkJClPgJ4OsAsgaFo2p142HRHJVFBE

Comment: At your gif tab2 scroll starting from `item 2` not `item 1`, it should start from `item 1`

Answer (score 0):

The reason behind this issue is that both tabs are using the same `TabController` which is in your case `DefaultTabController` which is impilictly defining tab controllers for children widgets, you have to explicitly set a separate `TabController` for each one of your tabs so its actions is independent of the other, but you will extra code to manage your new controllers:

here's the example:

inside your `nestedScrollView`

```
child: nestedScrollView(
controller: // add a `ScrollController` here
),
```

Comment: I didn't understand completely. I am new to flutter and mobile app development.

Comment: this article will clarify what I explained : https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/DefaultTabController-class.html

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping the `TabBarView` in a separate Scaffold which is inside a `StatefulWidget`. That way you can ensure that the tab body is rebuilt everytime you change the tab so the scroll position won't be preserved.

Example:

```
return Scaffold(
  body: DefaultTabController(
    length: 2,
    child: NestedScrollView(
      headerSliverBuilder: /* Your headerSliverBuilder code */
      body: MyCustomTabWidget(),
    )
);

class MyCustomTabWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return MyCustomTabWidgetState();
  }
}

class MyCustomTabWidgetState extends State<MyCustomTabWidget > {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: new TabBarView(
        children: [
          /*Code for both the Containers containing ListViews*/
        ]
      )
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: How can I open related tab content when user click to tabs if there is seperate `TabBarView`s for each tab?

Comment: My apologies I think I haven't explained it well in the example, it shouldn't be a separate `TabBarView` for each tab.
I meant to wrap the entire content on `TabBarView` inside a Scaffold which is in a `StatefulWidget`.
I'll update the example code accordingly.

Comment: Wrapping `TabBarView` with `Scaffold` solved problem, now when I scroll on tab1, tab2 not scrolling automatically but caused another problem: If I scroll down on the screen, `SliverAppBar` not scrolling automatically, `SliverAppBar` should scroll first then tab content should start to scroll.

Comment: I haven't tried running my example with `SilverAppBar` yet. I'll try running the code with `SilverAppBar` and post an update in some time.