# Flutter - How to have a NestedScrollView with a TabBar that can have pull-to-refresh and load-more (pagination, infinite-scroll)?

Tags: flutter

I am trying to achieve a `NestedScrollView` with a pinned and unpinned header on top, multiple tabs, in which each tab can be scrolled to load more items or pulled to refresh the contents of the lists.
Actual result: When using the `NestedScrollView` widget, `TabBar` lists scroll each other down and up, causing the header to have a "floating" effect even though it was marked as non-floating. Also, since it breaks the `NestedScrolLView`, I cannot use `ScrollController` with the `TabBar` lists, therefore cannot implement load-more functionality.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer to my question. According to what I learned by reading and reading on Github, the Flutter framework needs an extensive review of `NestedScrollView` to fix this known issue. The [extended_nested_scroll_view](https://pub.dev/packages/extended_nested_scroll_view) package solves the problem of working with a `NestedScrollView` and a `TabBar`.

```
return ExtendedNestedScrollView(
              onlyOneScrollInBody: true,
              headerSliverBuilder:
                  (BuildContext context, bool innerBoxIsScrolled) {
                // These are the slivers that show up in the "outer" scroll view.
                return <Widget>[
                  SliverToBoxAdapter(
                    child: ProfileHeader(
                      entityId: entityId,
                    ),
                  ),
                  ProfileTabBar(controller: tabController),
                ];
              },
              floatHeaderSlivers: false,
              body: ...); // TabBarView
        });
```

But if you use this, the inner scrollable views (in the tabs) cannot have their own `ScrollController`s, resulting in not being able to implement loading more functionality with `ScrollController`s. To overcome this problem, you can use the [infinite_scroll_pagination](https://pub.dev/packages/infinite_scroll_pagination). This package can be used with any architecture, I use it with the bloc pattern. raywenderlich has a nice guide explaining how it works, which you can access on the page of the package. I also tried using the [loading_more_list](https://pub.dev/packages/loading_more_list) package, but I could not get it to work, let alone work with bloc as well.

You can use the package I recommended with a `RefreshIndicator` to achieve a pull-to-refresh functionality as recommended on their pub. dev page.

I will not share code right now as it's still a work in progress, but once I am done I will share more snippets.